# API data in view source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side, next.js

I am using next.js to server-side render the react code, but when I view the source of the page I can see entire API data and redux store data.

Is it common for all SSR code or Am I making something wrong?

Comment: The data you fetch from API are rendered at server side unless you use dynamic loading.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. The premise of server-side rendering is to pass all the initial state to the browser in the first request and also render part of the DOM. That helps a lot for [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

Therefore, for a Single Page App to work the server rendered way, you must render part of the page and the rest of the page that is supposed to be rendered based on redux state must also be provided in some way.

After the initial rendering, you need to feed this state that came with the first rendering into the redux store.

That is how server-side rendering SPA works.